# vba on error trying to parse a null variant instead a string

Tags: json, vb.net, excel, vba, error-handling

inside excel i am looping a series of json strings that look like this.   but some times one of the values will come with null   instead a string.
so i try to do some error recognition but i am not getting the right stuff.
i would like to get a list    where the first item will be "Tool Training"  and since null fail with Type Mismatch in the second, i am trying a try except or an on error like this.

```
    Dim return_value As String     
On Error GoTo 22
    return_value = jstring("fields")("customfield_18711")("value")
22:
    return_value = "empty"

Resume Next
```

should only use resume? with out the next?
or i dont even use the resume at all?

this is how the json strings look like

```
{
"expand": "operations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields",
"id": "452637",
"self": "example.com/rest/api/2/issue/452637",
"key": "MP-16098",
"fields": {
"summary": "my summary",
"customfield_18711": {
"self": "example.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/48120",
"value": "Tool Training",
"id": "48120"
}
}
}




{
"expand": "operations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields",
"id": "452637",
"self": "example.com/rest/api/2/issue/452637",
"key": "MP-16098",
"fields": {
"summary": "my summary",
"customfield_18711": {
"self": "example.com/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/48120",
"value": null,
"id": "48120"
}
}
}
```

Comment: You said this is "inside Excel". Doesn't that mean your code is VBA and not VB.Net? If that is the case, please edit your question to replace the vb.net tag with excel-vba. That will bring your question to the attention of people who code VBA in Excel.

Comment: json is not just a fancy string, it is serialized data from an object. Use Json.NET to deserialize it instead of parsing it